# A problem with a definite integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to calculate the following integral on mathematica

```
Assuming[A ∈ PositiveReals && 
r ∈ PositiveReals && t ∈ PositiveReals && 
k ∈ PositiveReals,Integrate[-((k Cos[ϕ] Sin[k ϕ])/(A-2 r Cos[t - ϕ])), {ϕ, 0, 2 π}]]
```

but after some time it gives me back the uncalculated integral. Is it too complicated or is there a way to manipulate it and get the result?

Comment: Hint, it can solve with `(1 - Cos[t - phi])` but not with `(1 - 2*Cos[t - phi])`. So it looks like there is no analytic solution. Screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXnkS.png)  always simplify the integrand until you find at one point it becomes not solvable. All other parameters $r,k,A$ are not really needed to show this.

Answer (score 1):

Making use of the @Nasser's hint (If `A<=2*r`, then the integral does not exist, only its principal value. ), something can be done for concrete positive integer values of `k`. For example,

```
k = 4; Assuming[ A \[Element] PositiveReals && r \[Element] PositiveReals && 
 t \[Element] PositiveReals && A > 2*r, 
Integrate[(k Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[k \[Phi]])/(A - 
    2 r Cos[t - \[Phi]])), {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]]
```

> `(1/(r^5))2 I E^(-5 I t) \[Pi] (-A^4 + 3 A^2 r^2 - A^2 E^(2 I t) r^2 -  r^4 + E^(2 I t) r^4 - (4 (-A^2 E^(2 I t) + 2 (-1 + E^(2 I t)) r^2 +  A E^(2 I t) Sqrt[A^2 - 4 r^2])^2 (-A^6 E^(6 I t) +  A^4 E^(4 I t) (1 + 6 E^(2 I t)) r^2 -  A^2 E^(2 I t) (1 + 4 E^(2 I t) + 9 E^(4 I t)) r^4 +  2 (1 + E^(2 I t) + E^(4 I t) + E^(6 I t)) r^6 +  A^5 E^(6 I t) Sqrt[A^2 - 4 r^2] -  A^3 E^(4 I t) (1 + 4 E^(2 I t)) r^2 Sqrt[A^2 - 4 r^2] +  A E^(2 I t) (1 + 2 E^(2 I t) + 3 E^(4 I t)) r^4 Sqrt[ A^2 - 4 r^2]))/(Sqrt[ A^2 - 4 r^2] (-A + Sqrt[A^2 - 4 r^2])^5))`

Next, applying the `ComplexExpand` command, we obtain the result which takes 89.4 MB.

Comment: Numerical calculations confirm the above result for `A = 4; r = 1; t = 1;k=4;`

Comment: Even `ClearAll[A, t, r, k]; k = 1/2; Assuming[
 A \[Element] PositiveReals && r \[Element] PositiveReals && 
  t \[Element] PositiveReals && A > 2*r, 
 Integrate[(k Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[k \[Phi]])/(A - 
     2 r Cos[t - \[Phi]]), {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]]` returns the input.

Comment: `ClearAll[A, t, r, k]; k = 1/2; A = 4; r = 1; t = 1; Assuming[
 A \[Element] PositiveReals && r \[Element] PositiveReals && 
  t \[Element] PositiveReals && A > 2*r, 
 Integrate[(k Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[k \[Phi]])/(A - 
     2 r Cos[t - \[Phi]]), {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]]` returns a useless result with roots of quartic equations  which takes 31.4 MB.

Comment: Just for the completeness. `ClearAll[A, t, r, k]; k = 1/2; A = 
 1/2; r = 1; t = 1; Integrate[(k Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[k \[Phi]])/(A - 
    2 r Cos[t - \[Phi]]), {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 PrincipalValue -> True]` returns the input, producing a warning "PossibleZeroQ::ztest1: Unable to decide whether numeric quantity 1+(3 \[Pi])/2-I Log[I/4+Sqrt[15]/4]-2 I (Log[1-I Root[<<1>>&,4]]-Log[1+I Root[<<2>>]]) is equal to zero. Assuming it is".

Comment: `ClearAll[A, t, r, k]; k = 4; A = 
 1/2; r = 1; t = 1; Integrate[(k Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[k \[Phi]])/(A - 
    2 r Cos[t - \[Phi]]), {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 PrincipalValue -> True]` results in `1/8 \[Pi] (12 Sin[3] - 5 Sin[5])`.